# Popup on mouseover event in Kango browser extension development

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, content-script, kango-framework

I am developing a browser extension using [Kango Extension Framework](http://kangoextensions.com/)

By Using Content-scripts i have injected some code into the page like shown below

```
<span onmouseover= "hello('testing_name')" style='width:17%;padding: 3px; background-color: red; color: white; />
```

I have the hello(str) function definition in the same content-script only,

which is like below

```
function hello(test_name)
{
    alert(test_name);
}
```

But whenever i am trying to mouseover on the Span element , the 
`ReferenceError: hello is not defined` error is occurring.

What i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay , i have solved it by injecting external js file into the current loaded page, and wrote that function in that external js file. Now it is working fine